# Function to get Country from IP SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of ip ranges and corresponding geographic location.

Such as

```
IPFROM         IPTo    Code Country    City     State      Lat       Long   Zip       TZ
35009792    35010047    IT  Italy   Lombardia   Milan   45.46427    9.18951 20131   +02:00
35010048    35010303    ES  Spain   Madrid  Madrid  40.4165 -3.70256    28013   +02:00
35010304    35010559    BE  Belgium Brussels Hoofdstedelijk Gewest  Brussels    50.85045    4.34878 1210    +02:00
35010560    35011583    US  United States   California  Los Angeles 34.05223    -118.24368  90001   -07:00
35011584    35011839    SE  Sweden  Stockholms Lan  Solna   59.36004    18.00086    171 54  +02:00
35011840    35012095    DE  Germany Nordrhein-Westfalen Dusseldorf  51.22172    6.77616 40213   +02:00
35012096    35012351    AE  United Arab Emirates    Dubai   Dubai   25.25817    55.30472    -   +04:00
```

The IP range columns does not look like an IP.

The function would be like

Create Function GetCountryFromIP(@IP)

some code to get the country name and return it by function.

Execution example: Select dbo.GetCountryFromIP(123.123.147.213)

Comment: Would you please label the columns here to identify which column is which?

Comment: So how are the IPFROM and IPTo calculated if they don't look like an IP?  What code have you got so far?  This site isn't a "write my code for me", but a "I've tried this and I've got this problem/error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCountrytFromIP(@IP INT)
RETURNS VarChar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result VarChar(100)
  SELECT @Result = Country FROM Countries WHERE @IP BETWEEN IPFROM AND IPTO
  RETURN @Result
END
GO
```

Test Case (Should return 'Italy'). NB: I don't know how you are converting your IP address into INTEGERs. You will have to do that conversion yourself.

```
DECLARE @IP INT
SET @IP = 35009792
SELECT dbo.GetCountrytFromIP(@IP)
```

EDIT AFTER COMMENT:

OK, here is the revised function. It takes a VARCHAR(15) as an argument and returns the Country name. The IP address string is converted to a BIGINT using the SQL SERVER function PARSENAME (Not its intended use - [look it up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) - but handy for this purpose) and raising each octet of the IP address to a POWER (i.e. 256^3, 256^2 ...etc). The IPFROM and IPTO columns in the Country table must be a BIGINT data type to avoid arithmetic overflows.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCountryFromIP ( @IPAddress VARCHAR(15) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS 
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(100)
      DECLARE @IpBigInt BIGINT

      SET @IpBigInt = CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IPAddress, 1)) * POWER(256, 0)
        + CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IPAddress, 2)) * POWER(256, 1)
        + CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IPAddress, 3)) * POWER(256, 2)
        + CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IPAddress, 4)) * POWER(256, 3)

      SELECT
        @Result = Country
      FROM
        Countries
      WHERE
        @IpBigInt BETWEEN IPFROM AND IPTO
      RETURN @Result
    END
GO
```

Revised test case:
`35009792` converted into an IP Address is  `2.22.53.0`
So according to your Country table the following should return Italy

```
Select dbo.GetCountrytFromIP('2.22.53.0')
```

Comment: Thanks. The IP's in the table though are different from how a typical IP, is there a conversion that can be included in the function? e.g. how would you split the ip into octests like in http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/IP2Integer.jsp. So can we Send the IP as a string to function and then within function convert it to integer?